# Enlightenment DE 'Add Bryce' button adds toolbar that I seemingly can't remove?

Tags: desktop-environments, enlightenment

At Desktop > Add Bryce, there is a function to add a toolbar (with a menu arrow, a clock and some sort of Ethernet button) that I can't seem to remove. Does anyone know how to remove this?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is available here: http://www.enlightenment.org/ss/e-57e09cd253fd49.82605456.jpg

Shelves are top-left and top-right, mysterious toolbars in question bottom centre and middle left, peeking out from the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and do a right-click on the Bryce menu.
2. A context menu will appear.
3. Choose delete Bryce from the menu.

Comment: It worked, thank you. And I reckon that answer belonged in with the answers where it is, and not the comments.